# How to align li text left and set horizontal navigation under h3 tag?

Tags: html, css

I have page where I want to put navigation bar Menu on the left side of the page. I'm struggling to align text in a tag to the left side. I tried text align to all three elements a,ul and li but that still didn't fix the problem. Also I have the problem with my horizontal navigation bar. I would like to be aligned with h3 tag in my contentMain div. I'm not sure why my two div's are not next to each other as well. if someone can see where my code is off please let me know. Thanks.

```css
div.container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
  }
  .navMenuLeft {
      width: 180px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    background-color: white;
  }
  .navMenuLeft h3 {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background-color: #000099;
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 5px;
  }
  .contentMain h3 {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background-color: #000099;
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 5px;
  }
  .hfNavLeft {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  .hfNavLeft ul {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #d3d3d3;
  }
  .hfNavLeft li {
    text-align: left;
  }
  .hfNavLeft a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .hfNavLeft a:hover {
    color: #999999;
  }
  .contentMain {
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    background-color: white;
    min-width: 800px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10; IE=11" />
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">  
 <title>Home</title>
 
 
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="navMenuLeft">
   <h3>Menu</h3>
   <nav class="hfNavLeft">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="Reports/hfReports.cfm">Reports</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="contentMain">
   <h3>Home</h3>
   <nav class="hfNavTop">
    <a href="#" class="tablinks">Demographic</a>
    <a href="#" class="tablinks">Adult</a>
   </nav>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you sketch what you are trying to make? That way I might be able to help.

Comment: I need text Report to align left. That is inside li tag. Also I want navigation bar with the class hfNavTop to be aligned under h3 tag Home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell what you want... but I can explain the 'reports' alignment. It's in a `ul` tag - which has default padding and margins. `text-align: left;` is the default across the board for all elements already.

https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/tLbbzqws/

```
<aside class='sidebar'>
  <h2>Menu</h2>
  <nav class='y-navigation'>
    <ul class='item-list'>
      <li class='item'>
        <a href='#'>Reports</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</aside>

<section class='main-content'>
  <h1>Content</h1>
  <nav class='x-navigation'>
    <ul class='item-list'>
      <li class='item'>
        <a class='link' href="#">Demographic</a>
      </li>
      <li class='item'>
        <a class='link' href='#'>Adult</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</section>
```

...

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 30%;
  float: left;
  background: lightgreen;
}

.main-content {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 70%;
  float: left;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

Comment: I see that you have used aside and section tags. Can I place the table inside of the section? Are these tags HTML5 tags? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, they are HTML5 tags - and yes - you can place whatever you want in them. Some people would argue that section should only be used in an article - but - the developers get to really decide how these things work in the end.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to help and explain about the tags.

Answer (score 1):

I made several changes on your code. Is this what you want to achieve? `.navMenuLeft` and `.contentMain` next to each other?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.navMenuLeft {
  width: 180px;
}
.navMenuLeft h3 {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: #000099;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
.contentMain h3 {
  background-color: #000099;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
}
.hfNavLeft {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.hfNavLeft ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
}
.hfNavLeft ul li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.hfNavLeft a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.hfNavLeft a:hover {
  color: #999999;
}
.contentMain {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}
.contentMain .hfNavTop {
  margin-top: 12px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10; IE=11" />
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">  
 <title>Home</title>
 
 
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="navMenuLeft">
   <h3>Menu</h3>
   <nav class="hfNavLeft">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="Reports/hfReports.cfm">Reports</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="contentMain">
   <h3>Home</h3>
   <nav class="hfNavTop">
    <a href="#" class="tablinks">Demographic</a>
    <a href="#" class="tablinks">Adult</a>
   </nav>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure your require.
If you what align elements on the left side to left.
just add

`ul{
padding: 0;
}`